# how to convert Json to CSV file keeping the header separated?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I am quite new to programming. I am working with some json data scraped from Twitter.
I want to convert it to CSV, but the CSV file looks strange; I have all the title from the header in a row like that *_type,url,date,content,renderedContent,id,user,replyCount,retweetCount,likeCount,quoteCount,conversationId,lang,*

```
df = pd.read_json("2021-06-15.json", lines= True)
df.to_csv('test6.csv', sep = ",", index = None, header = True)
```

Highly appreciated any suggestions

Comment: That header looks ok to me. The separator `,` looks to be doing it's job. Try opening it in Excel or LibreOffice.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. I don't see the problem you have. Please include any error messages, or examples of what you expect vs. what you're getting. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.